# Style GWT FlexTable with CSS

Tags: java, css, gwt, widget, stylesheet

I'm trying to style a FlexTable Widget with CSS in my GWT Project.

This is what i have so far:

```
.gwt-FlexTable {
    background-color: #0000a0; 
    border: thick;
    border-color: black; 
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

not working. Anybody knows why? I am a beginner..

Comment: You should post a working example or we cannot help you only with a CSS snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.gwt-Flextable`, try `.flextable`